# Django input CSV file to create a new table. (CSV file convert into a table in the database)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I wanted some help with a project I'm working on:

So I have to take a CSV as input from the user and convert the CSV save it as a Table in the Database.

So I was able to take the input from the user and save it in the `MEDIA_ROOT`.
But now I'm unsure how to create a model without knowing the columns and so on. (I know I can get the columns from pandas(in views.py) but how to send that column details to models.py)

I'm new to Django and very much confused with so many files. Please help.

**Note:** I don't want to save the CSV file I want to convert it into a table in the database.

**views.py**

```
import pandas as pd
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, ListView, CreateView
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage


def home(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')


def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        upload_file = request.FILES['csvfile']
        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        fs.save(upload_file.name, upload_file)
    dataset = pd.read_csv('media/'+upload_file.name)
    colums = list(dataset.columns)
    
    return render(request, 'upload.html')
```

**models.py**

```
from assignment.settings import MEDIA_ROOT
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.fields import CharField
class CSV(models.Model):
    csvfile = models.FileField(upload_to='CSV')
```

Answer (score 0):

The best scenario here is to use a single model called `Files` and store CSV in a JSON field. You can easily read CSV as a Dict using csv.DictReader and save it in database.